# HDMI connecting cause logout (18.04 LTS)

Tags: drivers, upgrade, graphics, 18.04, hdmi

I lately bought a xp-pen drawing tablet, and on Ubuntu 14 it worked very well.

However, after I upgraded to 18.04, connecting it causes the screen to go black for while and then logout.
I have tried to  install NVIDIA drivers but without any success.

I have to note, that I made the following check: When I plug in this xp-pen using the live CD OS, it works well. I had checked and on the live Ubuntu there are the same drivers/modules as after the installation.

Software & update > additional drivers is completely empty.

Please can anyone help?

```
~$ lspci | grep ' VGA '
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Park [Mobility Radeon HD 5430/5450/5470] (rev ff)
```

```
$ lspci -knn | grep VGA -A3
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0046] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller [103c:144a]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
--
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Park [Mobility Radeon HD 5430/5450/5470] [1002:68e0] (rev ff)
    Kernel driver in use: radeon
    Kernel modules: radeon
01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cedar HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 5400/6300/7300 Series] [1002:aa68] (rev ff)
```

```
$ dmesg --level=err,warn
[    0.036000] core: CPUID marked event: 'bus cycles' unavailable
[    0.036324]  #2 #3
[    1.113124] [Firmware Bug]: Invalid critical threshold (0)
[    1.115231] (NULL device *): hwmon_device_register() is deprecated. Please convert the driver to use hwmon_device_register_with_info().
[    1.185927] rtc_cmos: probe of 00:01 failed with error -16
[    1.417549] r8169 0000:03:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control
[    1.458748] ATPX version 1, functions 0x0000002f
[   10.570367] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000428-0x000000000000042F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000400-0x000000000000047F (\PMIO) (20170831/utaddress-247)
[   10.570381] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000540-0x000000000000054F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000500-0x0000000000000563 (\GPIO) (20170831/utaddress-247)
[   10.570388] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000540-0x000000000000054F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000500-0x000000000000054F (\SGGP) (20170831/utaddress-247)
[   10.570394] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000540-0x000000000000054F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000500-0x000000000000055F (\_SB.PCI0.P0P3.PEGP.GPIO) (20170831/utaddress-247)
[   10.570401] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000530-0x000000000000053F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000500-0x0000000000000563 (\GPIO) (20170831/utaddress-247)
[   10.570407] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000530-0x000000000000053F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000500-0x000000000000054F (\SGGP) (20170831/utaddress-247)
[   10.570413] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000530-0x000000000000053F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000500-0x000000000000055F (\_SB.PCI0.P0P3.PEGP.GPIO) (20170831/utaddress-247)
[   10.570420] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000500-0x000000000000052F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000500-0x0000000000000563 (\GPIO) (20170831/utaddress-247)
[   10.570424] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000500-0x000000000000052F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000500-0x000000000000054F (\SGGP) (20170831/utaddress-247)
[   10.570428] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000500-0x000000000000052F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000500-0x000000000000055F (\_SB.PCI0.P0P3.PEGP.GPIO) (20170831/utaddress-247)
[   10.570432] lpc_ich: Resource conflict(s) found affecting gpio_ich
[   10.570435] lpc_ich 0000:00:1f.0: No MFD cells added
[   10.621799] hp_wmi: query 0xd returned error 0x5
[   12.075429] kvm: disabled by bios
[   12.129937] kvm: disabled by bios
[   12.165743] kvm: disabled by bios
[   13.532964] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: number of I/O streams is 30, forcing separate stream tags
[   13.636501] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: CORB reset timeout#2, CORBRP = 65535
[   13.636530] hdaudio hdaudioC1D0: no AFG or MFG node found
[   13.636539] hdaudio hdaudioC1D1: no AFG or MFG node found
[   13.636546] hdaudio hdaudioC1D2: no AFG or MFG node found
[   13.636552] hdaudio hdaudioC1D3: no AFG or MFG node found
[   13.636555] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: no codecs initialized
[   13.860481] uvcvideo 2-1.5:1.0: Entity type for entity Processing 2 was not initialized!
[   13.860483] uvcvideo 2-1.5:1.0: Entity type for entity Camera 1 was not initialized!
[   15.548137] Bluetooth: hci0: hardware error 0x37
```

Comment: Hi שמואל ביאליסטוקי, welcome to askubuntu! In order to see the drivers/modules in use, add the output of following command to your post: `lspci -knn | grep VGA -A3`

Comment: Yo have a 2 gpu. Did you get any system error messages? Post `dmesg --level=err,warn`

Comment: I have noticed that too, but didn't get any error massage..